# Yotzros for Musaf on Shabbos Shekalim

Tags: ashkenazi, nuschaot, four-parshiot, yotzrot

Those who have the custom to say the [Yotzros for Musaf on Shabbos Shekalim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47847&st=&pgnum=660) finish off each stanza with the following words:

אור פניך עלינו אדון נשא, ושקל אשא בבית נכון ונשא

Hey, wait a second, wasn't it a Machtzis HaShekel - so why does it say V'Shekel?

Comment: Incidentally, I wonder about the fifth word in that line. Shouldn't it be נסה (as in 'נסה עלינו אור פניך ה, Ps. 4:7)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the terminology used in the Mishnah, the Biblical shekel is called a sela, and the former half-shekel is called a shekel. (Examples are legion - see, for example, Shekalim 1:6: הנותן סלע ונוטל שקל - one who gives a sela and asks for a shekel as change.)

So it's quite correct to say that we will give a shekel.

Answer (score 3):

I heard that there is a Gemorah: If 2 people come together to pay the half Shekel they can give a shekel and they will have to pay a Kalbon (1/48 of a shekel) for a conversion fee

I heard a vort in the name of the Belzer Rov:
The Yidden wanted to give as much as they could, so they would come together on purpose to pay this extra Kalbon

אור פניך עלינו אדון נשא - we ask Hashem to favour us

ושקל אשא בבית נכון ונשא - to give us extra money so we will give a shekel and be able to pay extra

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yehuda Leib and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!